# Column sum based on conditions

Tags: r, column-sum

I had a problem when summing columns based on condition. Here, summing columns means `d23+d24+d25+d26+..+d31`. Below is part of my dataframe.

```
      d23  d24  d25   d26    d27    d28    d29    d30    d31
854 -0.60 4.11 8.52  0.90  -7.99 -10.27  -8.32  -6.79 -11.71
855 -1.14 2.66 8.14  0.11  -8.96 -11.25  -9.17  -7.84 -12.53
856 -1.16 0.71 5.45 -1.65 -10.72 -11.18 -11.58 -10.44 -14.29
857  0.08 5.36 9.59 -0.22  -9.79  -9.47  -9.44  -7.67 -10.57
858 -0.95 4.86 8.18 -4.03 -12.15 -11.19 -11.37  -9.47 -13.90
859 -0.70 3.72 8.60  1.87  -6.99  -9.77  -7.84  -6.20 -11.31
```

As you can see, there are positive and negative values. I want to sum across columns in such a way, if the value is positive, the set it as zero; if the value is negative, then take the absolute value of this value. Finally, sum across columns and create a new column.

Any idea how can I realize that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility could be:

```
colSums(abs(df) * (df < 0))

  d23   d24   d25   d26   d27   d28   d29   d30   d31 
 4.55  0.00  0.00  5.90 56.60 63.13 57.72 48.41 74.31
```

Comment: This looks like a row sum instead of a column sum. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: You can replace `culSums()` with `rowSums()`: `rowSums(abs(df) * (df < 0))`.

Comment: Can I use this for other conditions? Say, if the value is greater than 5, then set the value as the original value minus 5. Otherwise, set this value to be zero. Then sum across columns.

Comment: Sure, for that you can use something like `rowSums(((df > 5) * df - 5) * (df > 5))`.